# Coinbase Python Seems to Cache OAuth User

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

I'm adding Coinbase OAuth to my Django application and something seems to be caching the first user that was authenticated.

When the following code is run by the Django application it always returns the same user and accounts. I have verified that it is passing the correct user for the session but the `current_client_user` does not match.

```
client = OAuthClient(user.access_token, user.refresh_token)
current_client_user = client.get_current_user()
accounts = client.get_accounts()
```

Running the same code in the Django shell returns the correct user info and accounts.

What would explain this? I don't see any reference to caching in the Coinbase Python library documentation.